# How to make code run only if an exception was thrown?

Tags: java, exception

I have a try with several different catches after it. I have some "cleanup" code that only should be run if there was an exception thrown. I could add the same code to each exception, but that becomes a maintenance nightmare. Basically, I'd like something like the finally statement, but for it to only run if an exception was thrown.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are these runtime errors that you are catching or your own business errors.

Comment: IOException, ClientProtocolException, UnsupportedEncodingException, etc

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no direct support for this unfortunately. How about something like this

```
boolean successful = false;
try {
    // do stuff
    successful = true;
} catch (...) {
    ...
} finally {
    if (!successful) {
        // cleanup
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is to set a variable in each catch and then check for that variable in finally.

Pseudocode:

```
Boolean caught = false;

try {

    //risky code here

catch(err) {
    caught = true;
    // Do other stuff
}
catch(err) {
    caught = true;
    // Do other stuff
}
catch(err) {
    caught = true;
    // Do other stuff
}
finally {
   if (caught) {
       // Do clean up
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I could add the same code to each exception, but that becomes a maintenance nightmare.

Or if you blot out the 'exception':

> I could add the same code to each [place], but that becomes a maintenance nightmare.

This is what methods are made for.

```
private void cleanup() { /* clean up */ }

...

try {
    // oh noes

} catch (MyException me) {
    cleanup();
} catch (AnotherException ae) {
    cleanup();
}
```

Maintenance hassle gone!

Comment: Except that now you have no access to the stuff that's inside the caller.  If that's what needs cleaning up, you're hosed.  And if you pass the messed-up stuff in, then you're hard-coding the list of stuff to fix -- and if that list changes later on, you have to change every place that uses it.  And you will miss one.

Comment: Oh, and this `cleanup` function should *definitely* be `private`, if you insist on having it.

Comment: @cHao While ture and the finally is certainly nicer, if you miss one place the code just won't compile, so that's less bad still

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use simple try & catch?

```
try
{
    foo();
}
catch(Exception1 e1)
{
    dealWithError(1);
}
catch(Exception2 e2)
{
    dealWithError(2);
}
catch(Exception3 e3)
{
    dealWithError(3);
}

...

private void dealWithError(int i)
{
    if(i == 1) // deal with Exception1
    else if(i == 2) // deal with Exception2
    else if(i == 3) // deal with Exception3
}
```

Comment: exactly what no body should ever do. Nightmare on `if` street.

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping two layers of exception handlers, and rethrow the exception after you have done the common handling:

```
    try {
        try {
            // your code goes here

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            // do common exception handling for any exception
            throw t;
        }       

    } catch (NullPointerException nx) {
        // handle NPE
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        // handle any other exception
    }
```

Not sure I really like this solution though... feels like a bit of a hack. I'd probably rather see the Exception explicitly handled in each instance, even if this means repeating a call to some kind of shared cleanup function.